# how can add a new view / route into express?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'm new at this, I'm trying to absorb as much as possible.
I am using this template https://github.com/primaryobjects/Node.js-Bootstrap-Starter-Template
Okay, all right till here, but when I try to add a new page, it returns me the following error:

```
C:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:196
        throw new Error(msg);
              ^
Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\server\node_modules\express\lib\r
outer\route.js:196:15)
    at EventEmitter.app.(anonymous function) (C:\server\node_modules\express\lib
\application.js:481:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\server\app.js:31:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

The aim would be to answer me a new page at the following address:
http://localhost:3000/ask?america=

The steps I followed were:
Create a view and a path

```
/views/ask.jade
extends layout
block content
    div.container
    h1 ASK
```

2n

```
/routes/ask.js
exports.ask= function(req, res){
  res.render('ask');
};
```

3r

```
app.js
app.get('/ask', routes.ask);
```

But when I try to start "node app" returns me the error mentioned above.
Where am I mistaken?

Comment: If you put everything in app.js code so that it works: app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/respuesta', function (req, res) {
  res.render('respuesta');
});
But this is not a solution for me, I like the clean and structured code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried requiring specifically your routes/ask.js file? I'm pretty certain when using

```
require('folder')
```

require looks directly for an index file and uses that index file which I believe may mean that your routes/ask.js file might actually not be getting "required" by the app.

So

```
var askRoutes = require('./routes/ask')
...
...
app.get('/', routes),
app.get('/ask', askRoutes)
```

To modularize your code you could utilize your routes/index.js file as a routes module load file, where you load your route modules (like routes/ask.js) into your index file so you won't get bogged down by having a ton of required route modules in your app.js file. Just the index.js file would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the followings :

- use the default route first : `app.get('/', routes.index);` and then put your code after `app.get('/ask', routes.ask);`
- if it doesn't work, put instead of `res.render('ask');` the minimal return `res.send('some json');`